# MapReduce and iReport / Jasperserver (MongoDB)?

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, mapreduce, ireport, jasperserver

Does iReport support MapReduce ? (with MongoDB)
[image: simple query]
I would like to know if I can put a Map Reduce query in this windows, or if not on the report on jasperserver (When You upload you .jrxml you have a "Query" tab)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. For example:

```
{
  collectionName : 'dataByZipCode',
  sort : {
    'value.population' : -1,
  },
  mapReduce : {
    map : 'function () {
               emit (this.state, {population : this.pop});
             }',
    reduce : 'function (key, values) {
                  var total = 0;
                  for( var index = 0; index < values.length; index ++) {
                    total += values[index].population;
                  }
                  return {population : total}
               }',
    out : 'totalPopulation'
  }
}
```

See the [Jaspersoft MongoDB Connector Query Reference](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Bigdatareportingfornosqlandhadoop/Jaspersoft_MongoDB_Query_Language)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Jasperforge forums, it would appear to support the MapReduce query in Windows as per this update -

http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=96980

I have not tested this myself but it looks like iReport allows you to run any Mongo query you want.

Comment: Thanks ! I just would like an example then :)